# Retrieve only the value of an arrays sub-document field using MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "1"
},
"lastName": {
    "lastName": "James"
},
"data": [{
    "day": "20-09-2020 11:35:02",
    "hoursWorked": "0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs"
}, {
    "day": "20-09-2020 11:35:29",
    "hoursWorked": "0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs"
}]
}
```

How do I retrieve only the value of subfield "hoursWorked" of "data" field.
So, I need only the value or all values of such field, 0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs.

I use the following; however, I still cannot retrieve the value.

```
Document document = collection
                .find(new BasicDBObject("_id", y))
                .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("data.hoursWorked"), excludeId())).first();
        System.out.println(document);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use projection `$project`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "data.hoursWorked": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g3FVBLRpOTP)**

In spring boot, you need to autowire the mongoTemplate

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

The aggregation code,

```
public List<Object> test(){
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        a-> new Document("$project",
                new Document("data.hoursWorked",1)
        )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

**Update 1**

Using Bson.Doument

```
Document nodes = (Document) collection
                .find(new BasicDBObject("_id", "1"))
                .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("data.hoursWorked"), Projections.excludeId()))
                .first();

        List<Document> list = (List<Document>) nodes.get("data");
        for(Document d:list){
            System.out.println(d.get("hoursWorked"));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the post with my solution, but it still is not what I need. You use Spring. IS there a way not to use Spring?

Comment: Ahh, yes there are ways. have you tried https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-java-mongodb-projections

Comment: My solution gives me this: Document{{data=[Document{{hoursWorked=0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs}}, Document{{hoursWorked=0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs}}]}}

Comment: The solution from that link, gives me this : Document{{_id=5f5723aa557acc1651e56622, data=[Document{{hoursWorked=0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs}}, Document{{hoursWorked=0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs}}]}} . Question: how do I retrieve the "hoursWorked" field only?

Comment: `FindIterable<Document> documents= // your query.
MongoCursor<Document> iterator = documents.iterator();

List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Document nextDocument = iterator.next();
   list.add(nextDocument.get("hoursWorked"));
}

list.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: I haven't tested this, but this is the concept that you need

Comment: The solution you provided: list.add(nextDocument.get("hoursWorked")); -> gives me null

Comment: Did u Try with ir answer

Comment: I have tried all possible variations and it still gives me null

Comment: ahh, give me sometime, I will practically do it and let you know

Comment: @yaros I've updated my answer. Its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Using MongoDB Java Driver:

```
List<Bson> pipeline = 
    Arrays.asList(
        project(
             fields(
                 excludeId(), 
                 computed("hoursWorked", 
                      eq("$reduce", 
                          and(eq("input", "$data"), eq("initialValue", Arrays.asList()),
                              eq("in", eq("$concatArrays", Arrays.asList("$$value", Arrays.asList("$$this.hoursWorked") ) ) ) 
                          ) 
                      ) 
                  ) 
              )
          ),
         unwind("$hoursWorked")
    );

collection.aggregate(pipeline)
             .into(new ArrayList<Document>())
             .forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.get("hoursWorked")));
```

Prints two values from the `data` array:

```
0 hours : 5 mins : 321 secs
0 hours : 5 mins : 322 secs
```